# Longtabu not able to shrink text to textwidth

Tags: width, longtabu

I have a really long table with papers, their authors and some other info about the paper. I use `longtabu` to make it a long table, and as some papers have a lot of authors I would like to make sure that the tabu fits the width of the page as well. This is my table, which is the same pattern for ten papers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {ll}
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A Pushing Approach for Data Synchronization in Cloud to Reduce\\ Energy Consumption in Mobile Devices\end{tabular}}} \\
Authors                                                    & S. A. L. Carvalho, R.N. Lima and A.G. Silva-Filho \cite{Carvalho:PushingApproach}                                                     \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Adafruit INA219                                                                                               \\
Application type                                           & Networking application                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{An empirical study of the energy consumption of android applications}}                                                                          \\
Authors                                                    & D. Li, S. Hao, J. Gui and W.G.J. Halfond \cite{Ding:EmpiricalStudy}                                                              \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Monsoon power meter                                                                                           \\
Application type                                           & Networking application                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Calculating source line level energy information for android applications}}                                                                     \\
Authors                                                    & D. Li, S. Hao, W.G.J. Halfond and R. Govindan \cite{Ding:CalcSourceLine}                                                                \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Monsoon power meter                                                                                           \\
Application type                                           & Networking application                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Empowering Developers to Estimate App Energy Consumption}}                                                                                      \\
Authors                                                    & R. Mittal, A. Kansal and R. Chandra \cite{Mittal:EmpoweringDevelopers}                                                                          \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Monsoon power meter                                                                                           \\
Application type                                           & Networking application                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Estimating Mobile Application Energy Consumption using Program Analysis}}                                                                       \\
Authors                                                    & S. Hao, D. Li, W.G.J. Halfond and R. Govindan \cite{Ding:ProgramAnalysis}                                                                \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Atom LEAP                                                                                                          \\
Application type                                           & Various mobile applications                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Measurement and Analysis of Energy Consumption on Android Smartphones}}                                                                         \\
Authors                                                    & X. Li, X. Zhang, K. Chen and S. Feng \cite{Li:MeasurementAndroid}                                                                         \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Standard power meter                                                                                          \\
Application type                                           & Various Android components                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Measuring mobile phone energy consumption for 802.11 wireless networking}}                                                                      \\
Authors                                                    & A. Rice and S. Hay \cite{Rice:MeasuringWireless}                                                                                           \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & National Instruments PCI-MIO-16E-4                                                                            \\
Application type                                           & Networking application                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Optimizing Background Email Sync on Smartphones}}                                                                                               \\
Authors                                                    & F. Xu, Y. Liu, T. Moscibroda, R. Chandra, L. Jin, Y. Zhang and Q. Li \cite{Xu:OptimizingEmailSync}                                         \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Monsoon power meter                                                                                           \\
Application type                                           & Networking application                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Reducing Power Consumption in Android Applications}}                                                                                            \\
Authors                                                    & A. Singhai, J. Bose and N. Yendeti \cite{Singhai:ReducingPower}                                                                           \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Monsoon power meter                                                                                           \\
Application type                                           & Graphics application                                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Switching Push and Pull: An Energy Efficient Notification Approach}}                                                                            \\
Authors                                                    & D. Burgstahler, N. Richerzhagen, F. Englert, R. Hans and R. Steinmetz \cite{Burgstahler:SwitchingPushPull} \\
Platform                                                   & Android                                                                                                       \\
Logging equipment                                          & Hitex Power Scale with ACM Probe                                                                              \\
Application type                                           & Networking application      \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

However when I render this, some of the author names are outside of the textwidth. This is really bothering me, since I explicitly set the width to `\textwidth`. What am I missing?

EDIT: Changing `to \textwidth` to something like `to 0.2\textwidth` has no effect either, seems like `longtabu` is ignoring my width.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Tried with a new document, seems like there is some other setting in my long (50 pages) document which messes up the `tabu`

Comment: please fix the above example so people can run it and see the effect but note you have only used `l` columns which are always single line (like `\mbox`) and with very long text. You need some `p` or `X` columns which are like `\parbox` and allow line breaking within the cell.

Comment: Edited to full text, however rendering this works as expected. Tried changing l's to p's but got an error at \end{longtabu} saying `Package array Error: Missing arg: token ignored`

Comment: `p` takes a width `p{3cm}` or whatever width you want, you can't just change `l` to `p`

Comment: Solved it by changing l to X instead so the text wraps. Thanks for the pointers!