# Longtabu still not able to shrink text to textwidth even after using X columns

Tags: longtable, width, multicolumn, longtabu

My problem is very similar to this one:

[Longtabu not able to shrink text to textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240114/longtabu-not-able-to-shrink-text-to-textwidth)

where the table goes outside the page, even after I explicitly set the width to `\textwidth`. I also followed the solution from [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240114/longtabu-not-able-to-shrink-text-to-textwidth#comment570355_240114) and used `X` columns to allow line breaking within the cell, but the problem still persists.

I suspect that the problem is whenever using the `\multicolumn` command, since the other `\longtabu` tables on my document work just fine.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,openany]{book} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow specify input encoding
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % page dimensions
\usepackage{tabu} % tables that take more than 1 page 
\usepackage{longtable} % tabu needs this to be loaded 

\begin{document} 

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]| X[1,c,m]|} 
\hline 
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{ \bf Title of table goes here  } \endhead 
\hline 
\multicolumn{8}{| c |}{ Text  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{ Some long text here  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{ Some long text here  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{ Some long text here  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{ Some long text here  } \\
\hline 
{ 15  } & 
{ 14  } & 
{ 13  } & 
{ 12  } & 
{ 11  } & 
{ 10  } & 
{ 9  } & 
{ 8  } & 
{ 7  } & 
{ 6  } & 
{ 5  } & 
{ 4  } & 
{ 3  } & 
{ 2  } & 
{ 1  } & 
{ 0  } \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtabu} 


\end{document}
```

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to see the required width for the spanning entries if you calculate the columns widths directly. In which case you don't need `X` at allm so can use `longtable` rather than the wrapper provided by `tabu`.

Also, don't use `\bf` and only use `|` to the left of the *first* column.
If you use two `|` in all the `\multicolumn` entries then you get two adjacent rules, one in the right of a column and a touching one at the left of the next column.

The arithmetic just takes account that a `p` column takes up space equal to
the supplied width plus `\tabcolsep` space either side of the column, plus the width of any vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,openany]{book} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow specify input encoding
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % page dimensions

\usepackage{array,longtable} 
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr(\textwidth-17\arrayrulewidth-32\tabcolsep)/16\relax}
\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}{|*{16}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\mylength}|}}
\hline 
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\textbf{Title of table goes here}}
\endhead 
\hline 
\multicolumn{8}{| c |}{ Text  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ Some long text here  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ Some long text here  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ Some long text here  } & 
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ Some long text here  }\\
\hline 
{ 15  } & 
{ 14  } & 
{ 13  } & 
{ 12  } & 
{ 11  } & 
{ 10  } & 
{ 9  } & 
{ 8  } & 
{ 7  } & 
{ 6  } & 
{ 5  } & 
{ 4  } & 
{ 3  } & 
{ 2  } & 
{ 1  } & 
{ 0  } \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @DavidCarlisle, but I still can't fix my problem. Mainly because I'm not sure what to write instead of `| c |` i.e. `\multicolumn{2}{ ? }{ Some long text here }` What goes there?

Comment: @StalinRios updated answer

Comment: Thank you so very much @DavidCarlisle this wonderfully fixed the problem with this table. But now I created another problem for other similar tables. If the `\longtable` doesn't have any `\multicolumn` then the text overlaps with adjacent columns. I'd like to have the same format (`\begin{longtable}{...}`)for all my tables since they are generated from perl scripts. What do you recommend? Thanks again!

Comment: @StalinRios impossible to guess why you have overlapping text, unless you have long words that do not hyphenate to fit in the space?

Comment: I posted it as a new question here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267022/how-to-avoid-text-from-overlapping-adjacent-columns-using-longtable] I hope you can help me here too please. Thanks a lot!