# How to avoid text from overlapping adjacent columns using `longtable`

Tags: longtable, width, wrap

I need to use the same format (or pretty similar) at the start of the `\begin{longtable}{...}` and preferably the same `\mylenght` defined from the suggested fixes to my previous problem:

[First problem solved here...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266614/longtabu-still-not-able-to-shrink-text-to-textwidth-even-after-using-x-columns/266616?noredirect=1#comment639317_266616)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,openany]{book} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow specify input encoding
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % page dimensions

\usepackage{array,longtable} 
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr(\textwidth-17\arrayrulewidth-32\tabcolsep)/16\relax}
\begin{document} 


\begin{longtable}{|*{16}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\mylength}|}} 
\hline 
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\textbf{  Title goes here  } } 
\endhead 
\hline 
{\centering  15  } & 
{\centering  14  } & 
{\centering  13  } & 
{\centering  12  } & 
{\centering  11  } & 
{\centering  10  } & 
{\centering  9  } & 
{\centering  8  } & 
{\centering  7  } & 
{\centering  6  } & 
{\centering  5  } & 
{\centering  4  } & 
{\centering  3  } & 
{\centering  2  } & 
{\centering  1  } & 
{\centering  0  } \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr4\mylength+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ SEPTEMBER  } & 
{\centering  Lists 3 Ready  } & 
{\centering  Lists 2 Ready  } & 
{\centering  Lists 1 Ready  } & 
{\centering  Lists 0 Ready  } & 
\multicolumn{4}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr4\mylength+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ SEPTEMBER  } & 
{\centering  Lists 3 Not Empty  } & 
{\centering Not Empty  } & 
{\centering Not Empty  } & 
{\centering Not Empty  } \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable} 


\end{document}
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `{\centering  2  }` is exactly the same as `2` the `{}` remove the effect of the centering. If you needed it you could remove the `{}` and leave `\centering` but you have centering defined for the whole column anyway so you can just have `2`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the `\centering` but the problem still persists. Do you have any other suggestions? Do I have to adjust `\mylength` for each table?

Comment: The problem was already explained in the answer given. If you have so many columns that your words do not fit into the space you have to decide what to do, change the text, or use a smaller font, or rotate the headings or something. there isn't really any tex problem to solve. the comment about `{\centering`  was just a comment on the markup, as the answer has already been given.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately I can't use that answer to fix my problem. Please see my comment down below: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267022/how-to-avoid-text-from-overlapping-adjacent-columns-using-longtable%5D#comment640625_267036]

Comment: I don't see that your comment changes anything, you can not make something that is 2cm long fit in a 1cm space. You have to decide how to lay out your data in a way that fits the page.

Comment: I understand that, but is there a way to automate the splinting? It seems that `\longtable` doesn't split some words automatically. Do you know know to fix that? I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: longtable doesn't split _any_ words. you can specify  `\hyphenation{Em-pty}` or enter it directly as `Em\-pty` but it will probably look horrible, perhaps you should rotate the text or change the wording  or use a `\small` but it's not related to longtable in any way you would see the  same in a parbox of that width or on the main page if you set textwidth that small.

Answer (score 1):

The word "empty" is bigger than your `\mylength` you will have to do some thoughts on how you want this to be solved. The easiest would be to reduce the font size of course.

In the following code, I smashed everything into your table without touching the font-size. Not really pretty.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % I was hoping for some automatic breaks but this did nor work for "empty"
\usepackage{ragged2e} % I was hoping for some automatic breaks but this did nor work for "empty"
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % page dimensions
\usepackage{array,longtable} 
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr(\textwidth-17\arrayrulewidth)/16\relax}

\begin{document}    
\begin{longtable}{|*{16}{@{}>{\Centering\arraybackslash}m{\mylength}@{}|}} 
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\textbf{Title goes here}} 
    \endhead 
    \hline 
    $15$ & $14$ & $13$ & $12$ & $11$ & $10$ & $9$ & $8$ & $7$ & $6$ & $5$ & $4$ & $3$ & $2$ & $1$ & $0$ \\ 
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{SEPTEMBER} & 
    Lists 3 Ready & 
    Lists 2 Ready & 
    Lists 1 Ready & 
    Lists 0 Ready & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{SEPTEMBER} & % here was one | too much
    Lists 3 Not Emp-ty & 
    Not Emp-ty & 
    Not Emp-ty & 
    Not Emp-ty \\ 
    \hline 
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response @LaRiFaRi unfortunately, I can't manually split every single word that doesn't fit the column. I am generating all my tables suing a perl scrips thus it is impossible for me to try to manually split them all. Do you have any other suggestions?